# Insert data dynamically in a temporary table from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I want to insert data dynamically in a temporary table @temp  from the two different tables below table1 & table2

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

```
Declare @temp table ( Pays nvarchar (300), Factory nvarchar (300), Count bigint)
```

I tried this command but I have an error message : `Subquery returned more than 1 value.`

```
Insert into @temp select (select pays from table1),(select factory,count from table 2  where @Pays=’yes’)
```

The result sould be  like the table below `@temp`:

[image]

Thank you for you help.

Comment: How do you know that Factory SUX, DRV and HK are in France and not USA?

Comment: You are looking for a single select feeding your insert, with a join of Table1 and Table2. By the way, you haven't explaind how are those two related.

Comment: where is mapping table which says 'SUX' goes to 'France'

Comment: You have nothing in here that states how these tables would join together. And in your desired output you have rows that don't exist in the sample data. I would urge you to read what you posted and ask yourself if you think you would be able to answer this. Then go here (http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to see how to improve your question.

Comment: I have edited my question please take a look, I had hard time explaining what I actualy need, so please understand

Answer (score 0):

You want a [join (documentation here)](http://www.sql-join.com/) to run a a single select statement.

You may also want to read [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/highlighted-differences-between-sql-server-temporary-tables-andrew) as there are important distinctions between table variables (@table) and temporary tables (#table)

Answer (score 0):

first of all don't use keywords like Count as an attribute if you have to, then use like this -->[Count]

```html
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1
create table table1 (Pays nvarchar(300))
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2
create table table2 (Factory nvarchar(300), [Count] bigint)

/*temp table in sql should be created like this*/
create table #temp (Pays nvarchar(300),Factory nvarchar(300), [Count] bigint)
/*table variable should be created like this*/
Declare @temp table ( Pays nvarchar (300), Factory nvarchar (300), [Count] bigint)


insert into #temp(Pays) select Pays
from table1
insert into #temp(Factory,[Count]) select Factory,[Count]
from table2

Insert into @temp select Pays,Factory,[Count] from #temp
where Pays='yes'
go
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all don't use keywords like Count as an attribute if you have to, then use like this -->[Count]

```html
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1
create table table1 (Pays nvarchar(300))
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2
create table table2 (Factory nvarchar(300), [Count] bigint)

/*temp table in sql should be created like this*/
create table #temp (Pays nvarchar(300),Factory nvarchar(300), [Count] bigint)
/*table variable should be created like this*/
Declare @temp table ( Pays nvarchar (300), Factory nvarchar (300), [Count] bigint)


insert into #temp(Pays) select Pays
from table1
insert into #temp(Factory,[Count]) select Factory,[Count]
from table2

Insert into @temp select Pays,Factory,[Count] from #temp
where Pays='yes'
go
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but it seems that your data from table2 needs to be unpivoted in order to be able to join table1 and table2 to another. The following does exactly that.

```
declare @t2 table (Factory nvarchar(40), [Count] int, [France] nvarchar(300), [Morocco] nvarchar(300), [USA] nvarchar(300))
insert into @t2 values ('SUX',233,'YES','NO','NO')
, ('DRV',12,'YES','NO','NO')
, ('HK',144,'YES','NO','NO')
, ('MA',2016,'NO','YES','NO')
, ('ZER',2,'NO','YES','NO')
, ('RST',1777,'NO','YES','NO')
, ('ZE',24,'NO','NO','YES')
, ('VR',566,'NO','NO','YES')

select  unpvt.[Pays], unpvt.[Factory], unpvt.[Count], unpvt.[PaysInd]
from    
    (select [Factory], [count], [France], [Morocco], [USA]
     from @t2
     ) p
unpivot
    ([PaysInd] for [Pays] IN 
        ([France], [Morocco], [USA])
    ) AS unpvt
join @t1 countries on countries.[Pays] = unpvt.[Pays] and [PaysInd] = 'YES'
```